# PostgreSQL last_value ignore nulls

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, window-functions

I know this already been asked, but why doesn't the solution below work?  I want to fill `value` with the last non-null value ordered by `idx`.

What I see:

```
 idx | coalesce 
-----+----------
   1 |        2
   2 |        4
   3 |         
   4 |         
   5 |       10
(5 rows)
```

What I want:

```
 idx | coalesce 
-----+----------
   1 |        2
   2 |        4
   3 |        4 
   4 |        4 
   5 |       10
(5 rows)
```

Code:

```
with base as (

    select 1    as idx
         , 2    as value

    union

    select 2    as idx
         , 4    as value

    union

    select 3    as idx
         , null as value

    union

    select 4    as idx
         , null as value

    union

    select 5    as idx
         , 10   as value
)

select idx
     , coalesce(value
              , last_value(value) over (order by case when value is null then -1
                                                 else idx
                                                 end))
from base
order by idx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see why your solution doesn't work, just look at the output if you order by the ordering in your window frame:

```
with base as (
    select 1    as idx
         , 2    as value
    union
    select 2    as idx
         , 4    as value
    union
    select 3    as idx
         , null as value
    union
    select 4    as idx
         , null as value
    union
    select 5    as idx
         , 10   as value
)
select idx, value from base
order by case when value is null then -1
                                                 else idx
                                                 end;
 idx | value
-----+-------
   3 |
   4 |
   1 |     2
   2 |     4
   5 |    10
```

The last_value() window function will pick the last value in the current frame.  Without changing any of the frame defaults, this will be the current row.

Comment: I'm expecting idx 3 and 4 to have value 4, which is the last non-null value ordered by idx.  I'll update the question.

Comment: But doesn't the `order by case...` statement move all the nulls to beginning of the window?

Comment: It does move them to the beginning of the window, but the default frame of the window function is from the beginning of the window to the _current_ row.  So, last_value will return the current row, which is null.

Answer (score 8):

What you want is `lag(ignore nulls)`.  Here is one way to do what you want, using two window functions.  The first defines the grouping for the `NULL` values and the second assigns the value:

```
select idx, value, coalesce(value, max(value) over (partition by grp))
from (select b.*, count(value) over (order by idx) as grp
      from base b
     ) b
order by idx;
```

You can also do this without subqueries by using arrays.  Basically, take the last element not counting `NULL`s:

```
select idx, value, 
       (array_remove(array_agg(value) over (order by idx), null))[count(value) over (order by idx)]
from base b
order by idx;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=6027d6476fcabe50e2ede7f64cd938b8) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I understand and like your first solution, but why doesn't my solution work?

Comment: @GordonLinoff could you, please, comment on the performance of those queries? Will the option with array work for a large table?

Comment: They have locked it unless there is an edit in the answer.if u edit, I may undo it . Apologies for that

Answer (score 5):

Well the last_value here doesn't make sense to me unless you can point out to me. Looking at the example you need the last non value which you can get it by:
I am forming a group with the nulls and previous non null value so that I can get the first non value.

```
with base as (
select 1    as idx , 2    as value   union
select 2    as idx, -14    as value    union
select 3    as idx , null as value   union
select 4    as idx , null as value   union
select 5    as idx , 1   as value
)
Select idx,value,
first_value(value) Over(partition by rn) as new_val
from(
select idx,value
    ,sum(case when value is not null then 1 end) over (order by idx) as rn
  from   base
) t
```

here is the code

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/fcda4/2

Comment: Max(.) works if `value` is monotonic, as in the example, but not in general.

Comment: Do you want to share a sample data

Comment: Just change `select 2 as idx, 4 as value` to  `select 2 as idx, -4 as value`.  `your_value` for `idx` 3 and 4 is 2, instead of -4.